# IDEA shows branches as not covered that can't be reached (python)

Tags: python, intellij-idea, code-coverage

Given this function under test with coverage:

```
1    def func_to_test(param):
2
3        if param == 'foo':
4            return 'bar'
5
6        return param
```

And these two unit tests:

```
def test_given_param_is_foo_it_returns_bar(self):
    result = func_to_test('foo')
    self.assertEquals(result, 'bar')

def test_given_param_is_not_foo_it_returns_the_param(self):
    result = func_to_test('something else')
    self.assertEquals(result, 'something else')
```

The coverage view in IDEA shows that all lines of the function under test where hit but in line 3 (the line with the `if`) it shows this:

```
Line was hit
Line 2 didn't jump to line 4,6
```

I have the impression after looking at multiple of these cases that the coverage tool expects the `if` block to be executed and then the code execution to continue below the block. however this is not possible if the `if` block contains a `return` statement that has to be hit.

Do I misinterpret the message or is there anything else that I have to configure to have that detected correctly?

In my `coverage.rc` I have `branch = on`. But just disabling it would lead to reachable branches not being detected as "not hit".

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the same results.  When I run it, I get 100% for both statements and branches.  Maybe something is different about your code?

Here is my test run:

```
$ cat tryit.py
def func_to_test(param):

    if param == 'foo':
        return 'bar'

    return param


import unittest

class TestIt(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_given_param_is_foo_it_returns_bar(self):
        result = func_to_test('foo')
        self.assertEquals(result, 'bar')

    def test_given_param_is_not_foo_it_returns_the_param(self):
        result = func_to_test('something else')
        self.assertEquals(result, 'something else')

$ coverage run --branch --source=. -m unittest tryit
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK

$ coverage report -m
Name       Stmts   Miss Branch BrPart  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------
tryit.py      12      0      2      0   100%

$
```